# Argument of type 'NextRouter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props'

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript, next-router

I have a component where i am initializing my formik form by calling a function and sending router object of next/router as below

```
export default function Reset() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const formik = useFormik(RecoverForm(router));
  return (
          <form
            onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
          >
                <PlainInput
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  formik={formik}
                />

              <Button text="Send Email" type="submit" />
          </form>
  );
}
```

i am tring to send router object in Recoverform function which initialize formik and helps to navigate after successfull submittion of form

The line `const formik = useFormik(RecoverForm(router));` gives the following error

> Argument of type 'NextRouter' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Props'.   Property 'router' is missing in type 'NextRouter' but
> required in type 'Props'.ts(2345)

here is my code below for the function which generates the form and takes router object to navigate between the urls

```
import { NextRouter } from "next/router";
import { schema } from "./recover-schema";
interface Props {
  router: NextRouter;
}
export const RecoverForm = (router: Props) => ({
  initialValues: {
    email: null,
  },
  onSubmit: (values: any) => {
    router.push("/account/login");
    // Do something with the form values
  },
  validationSchema: schema,
});
```

It throws error

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Props'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two errors. the easiest way is to solve `Argument of type 'NextRouter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props'. Property 'router' is missing in type 'NextRouter' but required in type 'Props'.ts(2345)`:

```js
export const RecoverForm = (router: NextRouter) => ({
```

and remove the interface `Props`.

but in the future, you might want to add more parameters, so you can keep your interface `Props`, but use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and fix your `RecoverForm` call:

```js
const formik = useFormik(RecoverForm({ router }));
```

```js
export const RecoverForm = ({ router }: Props) => ({
```